# Filtering between two same date but different time - jasper

Tags: datetime, jasper-reports

I'm creating a jasper report which has the parameters of `datetrfrom` and `datetrto`.
The filtering goes well except when the the two parameters carry the same data such as

`datetrfrom>= '15-12-2012'`

`datetrto<= '15-12-2012'`

The data which are processed on the 15-12-2012 will not come out.

I tried this in my JSP :

```
function ShowReport(){
var param='';              

var timestart = ' 00:00:00'
var timeend = ' 23:59:59'

var datetrFrom = document.forms['report']['datetransfrom'].value;
datetrFrom.split("-")

    //i split n join back the date to change the format from dd-MM-yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd
    var dtf = [datetrFrom[6],datetrFrom[7],datetrFrom[8],datetrFrom[9],datetrFrom[5],datetrFrom[3],datetrFrom[4],datetrFrom[2],datetrFrom[0],datetrFrom[1] ].join('')
datetrfr = dtf + timestart; //i join the date with the timestart to create format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

    var datetrTo = document.forms['report']['datetransto'].value;
datetrTo.split("-")

    var dtt = [datetrTo[6],datetrTo[7],datetrTo[8],datetrTo[9],datetrTo[5],datetrTo[3],datetrTo[4],datetrTo[2],datetrTo[0],datetrTo[1] ].join('')

    datetrto = dtt + timeend; //i join the date with the timeend to create format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
    param = param + '@@dtTFrom=='+datetrfr+'@@dtTTo=='+datetrto;
```

`@@dtTFrom` and `@@dtTTo` are the parameters that I use in my jasper report.

This is what I do in the where clause in my jasper report:

```
where record_line_status='NO'
and datetime_process >= convert(date, $P{dtTFrom},105)
and datetime_process <= convert(date, $P{dtTTo},105)
```

But my report still does not work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem here.
This is my new coding in my JSP:

```
function ShowReport(){
            var param='';              

                        var timestart = ' 00:00:00'

                        var timeend = ' 23:59:59'

                        var orgFrom = document.forms['report']['org_id'].value;
                         param = param + 'orgFrom=='+orgFrom;       

                        var datetrFrom = document.forms['report']['datetransfrom'].value;
                        var datefromsplit = datetrFrom.split('-');
                        var datefromjoin = [datefromsplit[2], datefromsplit[1], datefromsplit[0]].join('-');
                        var datefromsend = datefromjoin + timestart;

                        var datetrTo = document.forms['report']['datetransto'].value;
                        var datetosplit = datetrTo.split('-');
                        var datetojoin = [datetosplit[2], datetosplit[1], datetosplit[0]].join('-');
                        var datetosend = datetojoin + timeend;


                        param = param + '@@dtTFrom=='+datefromsend+'@@dtTTo=='+datetosend;
```

and this is what I do in the where clause in my jasper report:

```
 where ep_lpp04_temp.record_line_status='No'
and EP_LPP04_TEMP.datetime_process >= convert(datetime, $P{dtTFrom}, 120)
AND EP_LPP04_TEMP.datetime_process <= convert(datetime, $P{dtTTo}, 120)
```

by the way my parameter class is

```
java.lang.string
```

.